# Ansible Playbook fails when executed through Jenkins, but works when executed on CLI

Tags: shell, jenkins, ansible

I need the files from a directory that match a particular pattern and the playbook below works at the command line but fails when executed within Jenkins.

Is there a solution for executing shell commands within Jenkins using an Ansible playbook that contains wildcard values?

Jenkins 2.319.2

This my playbook:

````yaml
- name: A Playbook to build artifacts
  hosts: targetservers
  vars:
    path_to_files: /opt/app/jenkins/sandbox_project_12345
  debugger: never
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  gather_facts: no
  remote_user: test_user
  ignore_errors: no
  tasks:
    - name: ping all
      ping:

    - name: List of files to be copied
      shell: bash -c 'ls {{ path_to_files + "/*006*" }}'
      delegate_to: localhost
      register: files_to_be_copied

    - name: Loop through files
      debug:  msg="{{ "Item = " + item  }}"
      with_items: "{{ files_to_be_copied.stdout_lines  }}"
       
    ```

TASK [List of files to be copied] **********************************************
fatal: [server.company_name.com -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "bash -c 'ls /opt/app/jenkins/sandbox_project_12345/2212.00*006*'", "delta": "0:00:00.010146", "end": "2022-10-25 14:34:54.516178", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 2, "start": "2022-10-25 14:34:54.506032", "stderr": "ls: cannot access /opt/app/jenkins/sandbox_project_12345/2212.00*006*: No such file or directory", "stderr_lines": ["ls: cannot access /opt/app/jenkins/sandbox_project_12345/2212.00*006*: No such file or directory"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
````

Comment: I'm not sure why you are expecting the Internet to know what's on your Jenkins machine. have you tried `shell: ls -la /opt/app/jenkins/sandbox_project_12345` or similar to see if there are any such files? When it does work for you, what is different about that circumstance versus the ansible one?

Comment: When you say `executed on CLI` do your mean `on the cli on the server where the jenkins server is running`?. Case NO (i.e. running on the cli somewhere else) then see comment from mdaniiel above. Case YES: are you using jenkins slaves and is your ansible job running on one of them? Case2 YES: are the files present on the given slave? Case2 NO: please [edit] your question and more details and debugging info

Comment: Moreover: getiting a list of files with `ls` running in `command`/`shell` is a bad practice. See the [`find` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/find_module.html)

Comment: For clarification - I was running the playbook from the Master server, both at the command line and Jenkins, which is running on the same server. After looking at everyone's comments, Zeitounator's suggestion is what helped resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the error message:

```
 "stderr": "ls: cannot access /opt/app/jenkins/sandbox_project_12345/2212.00*006*: No such file or directory"
```

the hypothesis that I would start investigating are:

- Does the path exist? My guess is that it would exist, based on the comment "*...works at the command line*"
- Will the user in the playbook have permissions to read in that directory? Ansible's user, defined in your ansible.cfg can have different permissions, or be part of different groups than the ones used in the "*command line*" test; if this is the case, you will need to use *become_user* (as a last resource *become*), more information is available [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html)
- Using shell to find patterns is flimsy and prone to errors, the suggestion is to use [Ansible's **find** module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/find_module.html).